# Rendering custom controls using Razor in MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a view model that contains two properties.

```
public class ControlToRender
{
     public int IsText { get; set; }
     public string LabelString { get; set; } 
     public string TextValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is populated  in the controller so that:

```
IsText = True;
LabelString = "please enter your name";
TextValue = "";
```

Within my view, I am testing the above as follows:

```
if (Model.IsText)
{
    @Html.CtrlHelper().ClearableTextBoxFor(model => model.TextValue, 
          new
          {
                placeholder = Html.Encode(placeHolder),
                @class = "js-text-option-text",
                @onchange = "javascript:alert('excellent!!!')"})
}
```

And finally, my HTML helper code:

```
static void CreateClearableTextBoxFor(object htmlAttributes, 
            decimal? additionalCost, out IDictionary<string, object> attrs,  
            out string anchorHtml)
    {
        attrs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (attrs.ContainsKey("class"))
            attrs["class"] = String.Concat("js-text-option-clear ", attrs["class"]);
        else
            attrs.Add("class", "js-text-option-clear");

        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.AddCssClass("js-text-option-clear-button text-option-clear js-toolTip tool-tip");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("title", "Clear");
        if (additionalCost != null && additionalCost > 0)
        {
            anchor.Attributes.Add("data-additionalcost", additionalCost.ToString());
        }
        anchorHtml = anchor.ToString();
    }
```

This code compiles ok, and renders on the screen, but when I change the text in the control, the onchange event is not fired.

I have looked at the generated hmtl output to see that the onchange event has not rendered at all.

Can someone please point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have sorted it out.

The code change I made was as follows. In the HMTL helper I added:

```
attrs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
if (attrs.ContainsKey("class"))
    attrs["class"] = String.Concat("js-text-option-clear ", attrs["class"]);
else
    attrs.Add("class", "js-text-option-clear"); 

 /* NEW LINE BELOW */
 attrs.Add("onchange", "javascript:alert('Booooooom');");
```

This now causes the onchange event to fire correctly.